# Org-mode & Elisp: How does one switch the buffer when using an ID to visit an entry?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to write an Elisp function that opens an Org-mode entry given its ID and operates on that entry. When using `org-open-link-from-string` from `org.el` and the value of the entry's `ID` property, however, Emacs appears to jump to the entry (i.e., the entry's buffer appears, and the cursor moves to the correct entry), but any code that follows the call to `org-open-link-from-string` seems to operate on the original buffer.

For example, suppose you evaluate the following code in `*scratch*`, where `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX` is a legit Org-mode ID in a file called `Test.org`. Again,

- `*scratch*` is the buffer in which you evaluate the code below
- `Test.org` is the buffer that contains the Org-mode entry with ID `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Here's the code to evaluate while in `*scratch*`:

```
(defun testfn-visit-org-entry (id)
  (org-open-link-from-string (concat "id:" id))
  (message "%s" (current-buffer))
  )
(testfn-visit-org-entry "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

The Emacs cursor jumps to the correct entry in `Test.org`, but `message` prints `*scratch*`, the buffer we started in. Moreover, additional code that might follow the call to `org-open-link-from-string` operates in `*scratch*`, not `Task.org`.

**Is there a way to fully jump to the entry corresponding to `ID` and actually switch to the appropriate buffer within the context of the Elisp function?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
(defun open-id (id)
 (org-id-goto id)
 (message "%s" (current-buffer)))
```

That seems to do what you want.